# Access 2010 App - How to Address Missing Unicode Characters on Windows 7?

Tags: ms-access-2010, unicode-string

**Background**

Access 2010 application developed on Windows 10.

The user interface uses some unicode characters to succinctly identify button uses (tool tips expand to fully describe those uses).

***Examples***

A comment button uses a "speech bubble" unicode character (`&H1F5E9` /  `128489`).

[image: Comment icon use]

Another instance uses the eye and ballot x for visibility and deletion.

[image: Visibility and delete icon use]

The unicode value is set as the button's `.Caption` property (translated as a string).

This works well in Windows 10 and allows me to easily change color depending on the situation - for example setting the eye to red when data is *not* externally visible or green when it *is* publicly visible.

**Problem**

The problem is that these unicode characters do not properly display in Windows 7.

**Constraints**

For a solution to be workable, it needs to:

- Address the unicode characters that don't work in Windows 7
- Provide the same images in the button displays (*e.g. eye is still the eye*)
- Provide the same colors in the button displays (*red vs. green as described above*)
- Resize properly when a form changes size (*different screen resolutions*)

A viable solution cannot:

- Require installation of fonts or other software (*Access database must be stand alone*)

***Bottom Line***

I'm wondering what others would consider a viable solution.

One thought I'd had would be to change the missing unicode characters to images and somehow embed them in an icon table within the database. But am unsure how to proceed.

It seems that the characters would have to be made like an icon with transparency to let the button shading show through.

I'd chosen the unicode route as I could readily change coloration and the characters cleanly appeared -- no messy jaggy edges like one often sees with homemade icons displaying on a non-white (*or different colored*) background.

I've searched and not quite found the right path.